# Set quota for pods with the same namespace for Openfaas with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openfaas

I deploy some functions using Openfaas over Kubernetes. Openfaas function is using `openfaas-fn` namespace which I can set quota for.

The question is how if I want to group functions (kind of labeling) and set quota for each group of functions. Meaning `fn1, fn2, fn3` limited to `1Gi` memory but `fn4, fn5, fn6` limited to `3Gi`. Is there any way to manage quota in this way?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately quotas in Kubernetes apply to namespaces only.

Comment: Is there any solution workaround to apply on openfaas?